# If I link external javascript, does it run after the dom is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

Do I have to use a callback like this:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

or can I assume that if I use an external file for javascript that I am safe?

Comment: There are several ways. Include your script tags just before `</body>` - then they can't run until the page loads, because they load afterwards. They should be there anyway.

Comment: I can't load them in the <head></head> section? Is it standard practice to stick them at the bottom?

Comment: We have been told in the past to put JS in the head but standard practice is to place JS before `</body>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also

```
<script onload="">
```

And as suggested in comment on op post.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script onload="">
  </head>
  <body onload="">
    <!-- Dom here -->
    <script onload="">
  </body>
</html>
```

The first script MIGHT be loaded before dom is loaded. (depending filesize and dom complexity)
On the second script tag the script will start loading after the dom is there.

Comment: That is so tricky! This does not seem as safe as putting it before </body>

Comment: @smuggledPancakes Actually putting it at the bottom of the body *can* ensure you to have the dom fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `$(document).ready()` [(.ready)](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)  can be used to run the code that should be executed after dom is fully loaded.

Comment: `document.body.onload = function(){ };` in js without jquery.

Comment: This is not a jQuery question